# How to periodically restart FastAPI on condition

Tags: fastapi

We have an external library, that requires starting FastAPI wrapped in a context manager, like this:

```
def start_server():
    with required_context_manager():
        uvicorn.run(app)
```

The problem is, that the library might hold stale data and the context_manager has to be restarted after some time of activity. The restart can only take place if there is no heavy task running, and we can't use uvicorn reload option, as it opens the app in another thread, so the context manager is not applied. How can I approach this?

Comment: Now I don't know what this external library does, but the fact that it has to be run "around" uvicorn (and not in e.g. a FastAPI lifespan function) seems really weird to me, as it prevents you running multiple worker processes. The fact that it also has no way of reloading its state without restarting the app seems even wierder. Can you share what library this is and why you need it?

Comment: @M.O. The library is privately developed inside the company. The library is a way to access the wider tool, most users don't use the Python package at all, and the tools using FastAPI are just a few, so we are at the bottom of the priority list. It runs "around" uvicorn because it is designed like Trio's nurseries. The state reload is just my approach to fix the issue that only affects my project.